# Using Javascript/jquery how can I get values from each cells in a selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to get and assign each cell value in a row to a variable.In particular the check box values

Here is an example of the table

```
<table id="mytable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <b><tr><th>Header1</th><th>Header2</th><th>Header2</th><th>Header3</th></tr></b>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>
            <label><input id="divpriority" ng-model="priority" type="checkbox" /> Option1</label>

            <label><input id="divsource" type="checkbox" /> Option2</label>

            <label>  <input type="checkbox" checked/>Otion3</label>
        </td>                   
        <td><br/><br/><button id="buttonvalues" type="button" class="btn-primary">GetValues</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So when the "GetValues" button is clicked in the current row the values from each cell are assigned to a variable.

I was thinking of something along the lines of this:(I know this is likely incorrect)

```
  $("#mytable table tbody ").on("click", "#buttonvalues", function() {
     var header1;
     var header2;
     var Options = new Array()

   var header1 = $(this).closest('tr').header1.val ;
   var header2 = $(this).closest('tr').header2.val

  Options = //Not sure what to do here
```

Using Javascript/jquery how can I get values from each cells in a selected row and assign the values to a variable with the click of a  button included in the row.

Please emphasize on assigning the name of the label from the check box into an array variable. I would like to get the name of the checkbox thats checked into the array

Comment: But the checkboxes do not have `name` attributes, do you mean the labels' text content? Also IDs must be unique.

Comment: Thats correct. The labels text\

Comment: quick comment:  your html is missing tbody

Comment: @thtsigma That's one element that pretty much all browsers will add for you. If you omit `<tbody />` from the HTML, it'll still show-up in the DOM. It's kinda like how you don't have to use closing `</li>` tags.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks @Jasper I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to save off each cell value in the row something like this will work.

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/vQas5/)</kbd>

Code:

```
$("#mytable").on("click", ".btn-primary", function () {
    var values = [];
    var $header = $(this).closest('table').find('thead th');
    var $cols   = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');

    $header.each(function(idx,hdr) {
        var $curCol = $cols.eq(idx);
        var $labels = $curCol.find('label');
        var value;

        if($labels.length) {
            value = {};
            $labels.each(function(lblIdx, lbl) {
                value[$(lbl).text().trim()] = $(lbl).find('input').is(':checked');
            });
        } else {
            value = $curCol.text().trim();
        }
        values.push( { name: $(hdr).text(), value: value } );
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
});
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Header1",
    "value": "value1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Header2",
    "value": "value1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Header3",
    "value": {
      "Option1": false,
      "Option2": false,
      "Option3": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Header4",
    "value": "GetValues"
  }
]
```

To get the name of each checked option in an array, change the header loop to:

```
$header.each(function(idx,hdr) {
    var $curCol = $cols.eq(idx);
    var $labels = $curCol.find('label');
    var value;

    if($labels.length) {
        // Filters for labels containing a checked checkbox
        value = $labels.filter(function(lblIdx) {
            return $(this).find('input').is(':checked');
        }).map(function(valIdx, valLbl) {  // Maps the result to the text value of the label
            return $(valLbl).text().trim();
        }).get();  // returns just the array of values
    } else {
        value = $curCol.text().trim();
    }
    values.push( { name: $(hdr).text(), value: value } );
});
```

Output <kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/vQas5/2/)</kbd>:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Header1",
    "value": "value1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Header2",
    "value": "value1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Header3",
    "value": [
      "Option1",
      "Option3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Header4",
    "value": "GetValues"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is great. Instead of getting true or false from the options I would like to get the name of the label instead as an array . Like value": {
      "Option1",
      "Option2",
      "Option3"
    }

Comment: @Milligran I've added an example of returning an array of label values based on what is checked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to get the values for a row when the row is clicked-on. If that's the case then your selector could be: `$("#mytable").on("click", ".btn-primary", ...`. And to get the values of the checkboxes: `var priority = $(this).closest('tr').find("input").eq(0).val();`

I'd suggest placing classes on the checkboxes in each row so you can select by that class rather than depending on the HTML structure always being the same an using `.eq(0)`. Your current use of IDs is not specifically valid as they are supposed to be unique in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique, you should use classes instead, assuming you have changed the IDs to classes you can use `.map()` method which returns an array:

```
$("#mytable").on("click", ".buttonvalues", function() {
     var options = $(this).closest('tr')
                          .find('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
                          .map(function() {
                              return $.trim( $(this).parent().text() );
                          }).get();
});
```

Please note that `$("#mytable table")` doesn't select a table that has `mytable` ID attribute. It selects descendant tables of `#mytable` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/oREJEKo/1/edit

```
$('#mytable').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var checkboxes = $($(this)).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var myvalues = [];
  $(checkboxes).each(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
       myvalues.push( $(this).closest('label').text() );  
    }
  });

  console.log(myvalues);
});
```